# Are questions asking for an off site resource on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

This [question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/38172/online-resources-for-workout-routines-in-a-gym) was recently asked and on most stack exchange sites would be considered off topic as it's asking for an off site resource. However, in your [off topic guidelines that is not mentioned](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (Closest I can find is *a purchase recommendation*).

Should it be considered off topic?

Answer (score 2):

From our "[don't ask](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" section:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

Also, on the subjective question portion:

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
>
> tend to have long, not short, answers
>
> have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
>
> invite sharing experiences over opinions
>
> insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
>
> are more than just mindless social fun

The question violates most if not all of those, I have closed it accordingly.